# DB wrapper library for SQLite for iOS development

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I am a beginner iOS developer and looking for a easy to use database wrapper library to use SQLite in iOS (Iphone, Ipad) applications. So far, I have found [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

What do you guys use to make enterprise wide Iphone database application? What is an easy to use and reliable DB wrapper library that I should look into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you need/want direct SQLite interaction, [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) is an excellent choice. It offers a simple and robust interface to the SQLite C API.

You might also want to consider [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html), the iOS framework for "object life-cycle and object graph management, including persistence," which generally uses SQLite behind the scenes.

As the Core Data documentation says "Core Data is not a relational database or a relational database management system (RDBMS)." The Core Data [Technology Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTechnologyOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009296-SW1) clearly delineates precisely what Core Data is and what it is not.

Having said that, for many applications, it offers a number of advantages over interfacing directly with SQLite, itself, and its worthwhile considering Core Data before you simply dive into SQLite programming yourself.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not correct. Core Data is an object graph framework which happens to use a database as store. It is NOT a database interface. You quickly run into all kinds of issues if you want to use it like a pure database API

Comment: @JorisMans Quite right. I thought the link made that clear, but I have nonetheless clarified my answer. I still contend that Core Data still a good starting point for many apps (rather than just diving into SQLite code), but there are certainly applications for which SQLite is better suited.